# Why this code throws a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i've the following code and I don' t know, why a NullPointerException is thrown:

```
//File DungeonObject.java

public class DungeonObject
{
// === OBJECT LIST === //   
public static final DungeonObject dirt = (new DungeonObjectDirt(0)).setName("#").setTexture("dirt");

// === GLOBAL DUNGEON OBJECT === //
public static int objectID;
public static DungeonObject[] objectList = new DungeonObject[16];

private String name;
private Texture texture;

public DungeonObject (int id)
{
    if (objectList[id] != null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The slot " + id + " is already used by " + objectList[objectID].toString());
    } else {
        objectID = id;
        objectList[objectID] = this;
    }
}


public DungeonObject setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public DungeonObject setTexture (String key)
{       
    this.texture = GameManager.getTextureManager().getTexture(key);
    return this;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Dungeon Object: " + this.name;
}
}
```

When calling

```
System.out.println (DungeonObject.dirt);
```

Comment: Because `DungeonObject` is `null`.

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: `System.out.println (DungeonObject.dirt);` Compilation error, no static field `dirt` is declared, at least in the code you posted.

Comment: That line will never throw an Exception if DungeonObject is an class.  More likely it won't compile unless `dirt` is statis.

Comment: @m0skit0 He didn't post the relevant code. Otherwise he'll never get this exception from this line.

Comment: @MarounMaroun `DungeonObject` cannot be null because it's not an instance.

Comment: @m0skit0 `dirt` is not declared, full stop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's what I said :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the asker posted a code which has no relationship whatsoever with the problem he has.

Comment: I've added the complete source-code :D

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac I don't think so :(

Comment: I need **help** ! :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What fails is the initialization of your class:

```
public class DungeonObject
{
public static final DungeonObject dirt = (new DungeonObjectDirt(0)).setName("#").setTexture("dirt");

...

public static DungeonObject[] objectList = new DungeonObject[16];

public DungeonObject (int id)
{
   if (objectList[id] != null)
    ....
}
}
```

1. The `dirt` field's static initializer runs;
2. it calls the `DungeonObject` constructor;
3. the constructor dereferences `objectList`;
4. which is `null` at that point because its declaration occurs below `dirt`.

Comment: I just moved `public static DungeonObject[] objectList = new DungeonObject[16];` in front of `public static final DungeonObject dirt = (new DungeonObjectDirt(0)).setName("#").setTexture("dirt");` and now everythink works!

Comment: Yes, that was the thing to do.